# Merge array within array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, object

I have an array containing a further 2 arrays of objects and I wanted to turn it into a single array of objects. I have posted the current code and result I want

I have tried the concat method but possibly implementing wrong?

```
var code = [
  [{Adults:"1", Price: "14.50"}],
  [{Adults:"1", Price: "20.50"}]
]

var result = [
  {Adults: "1", Price: "14.50" },
  {Adults: "1", Price: "20.50"}
]
```

Comment: Hi @MaheerAli typo this has been fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**flat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
var code = [
  [{Adults:"1", Price: "14.50"}],
  [{Adults:"1", Price: "20.50"}]
]

let op = code.flat()

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Note that `flat` is not supported by sh`ie`t and edge

Comment: @AntihypeBird edge will eventually start using chromium and you can use polyfill easily, it given [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Polyfill)

Comment: it will for sure, just a note for current versions :)

Comment: @CodeManiac just because edge will support eventually doesn't negate the fact that lots of enterprise users use old versions of IE still :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell we have polyfill for such cases, there are lots of features which are not supported by `IE`

Comment: As a top user under the js tag, you should put your efforts into curating this site instead of answering obvious dupes.